# Reading a file from external SD card in android Marshmallow 6.0.1 giving fileNotFoundException open failed: ENOENT

Tags: android, base64, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to read a file from external SD card in android Marshmallow 6.0.1 and want to convert in Base64, but it is giving ENOENT(fileNotFoundException). But my same code is working for 6.0 and below. My code is as follows:

```
private String convertFileToByteArray(File file) { //file path as: /storage/emulated/0/abc.doc
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {

            File f=new File(file.toString());
            Log.e("File EXISTs: >>",""+f.exists());

           //getting error in this line,giving fileNotFoundException
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

            Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Can any one suggest me what's wrong i am doing here. PS: I am giving runtime permissions also(read and write).

Comment: `Log.e("File EXISTs: >>",""+f.exists());` And... what does it print? And why are you continuing with the code if it does not exist? You shoud display a Toast() and return.

Comment: `read a file from external SD card` ? Dont think so as `/storage/emulated/0/abc.doc` is externaml memory. Not on an SD card.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`. If there is a catch you should display a Toast with e.getMessage() and return. Now you continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: @greenapps yes sir, i know that i can return as soon as it says file don't exist. But the thing is i want to submit it to the server and same code is working in marshmallow 6.0 but not in 6.0.1. that's y asked this question.

Comment: You already told that. We already knew. This does not bring you further. Meanwhile you could have given more info. For example what is the value of .exists()? And what is the file size? And why are you not reacting to all of my comment? You ask help. Get help. But do not react.

Comment: @greenapps sir, u got me wrong. I am not reacting at all, and value of .exist() is false.The file size is around 2 mb and i am using FileUtils class which is returning the absolute path of the file. I am able to get absolute path but while going to convert that file in byte array it's giving fileNotFoundException. It's happening in 6.0.1 but not in 6.0

Comment: The File class already told you that your file does not exist. But you blindly continue with your code and try to open a stream. And then talk about a FilNotFoundException. Of course the file is not found. And you already knew.  You should have returned right away. Now why does the File class not find your file? Well show its full path. And FileUtils class is something you made yourself?

Comment: No sir i got FileUtils class from github and my full path is like (/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/different_images/Doc_RequiredStrings.doc) this.

Comment: Why are you putting .doc files in the DCIM folder?

Comment: @greenapps even, I am keeping file outside of DCIM folder same thing is happening sir.

Comment: You should check if the file exists before you call your function. Just check it on other occasions too. And by now you know that that path is not on SD card i hope.